# Here I have some sheet with column 1:

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

Im new in pandas so would like to ask some help according to excel file. 
Here I have some sheet with column 1:

```
Index   Column1
1       PF7293 
2       NodeB Name=SN5208, LogicRNCID=106
3       KL5083
4       Label=DL7765A3U-2, CellID=28643, LogicRNCID=201
```

and I wanna create another `column2` that should have some word from `column1` and look like that:

```
Index Column2
1     PF7293 
2     SN5208
3     KL5083
4     DL7765
```

in excel we used `MID`. I would like to do the same using pandas. Thank you!

---

Question 2

New sheet looks like that:

```
Column1    Column2 
KL7110     BTS works 
KS5007     BSS works 
KL5066     Planned works 
KL5147     Planned works 
KL5066     Unplanned work 
KL5077     Power work
KL5077     Power work 
AN9045     MW work
```

I wanna delete same value from Column 2 for one value in column1. 
For example here is 2 KL5077 in column1 with same value in column2 I would Like to delete one of them. 
And second problem here is 2 KL5066 in Column1 with different value in Column2 and in this case I would like to put values in Column2 together like "Planned work/Unplanned work". Hope I ve explained well))

Comment: Gosh, Im sorry, Ive written in normal way recognisible for  eyes, and website stick everything together, Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

You could try [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['Column2'] = df['Column1'].str.extract(r'([A-Z]{2}\d{4})')
```

Where the `regex` pattern here can be though of as "2 uppercase letters" followed by "4 digits"

[out]

```
   Index                                          Column1 Column2
0      1                                           PF7293  PF7293
1      2                NodeB Name=SN5208, LogicRNCID=106  SN5208
2      3                                           KL5083  KL5083
3      4  Label=DL7765A3U-2, CellID=28643, LogicRNCID=201  DL7765
```

---

#### Update

For the 2nd problem:

1) To drop duplicate rows use:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Column1', 'Column2'], inplace=True)
```

2) To join multiple 'Column2' values use:

```
df_new = df.groupby('Column1')['Column2'].apply('/'.join).reset_index()
```

[out]

```
  Column1                       Column2
0  AN9045                       MW work
1  KL5066  Planned works/Unplanned work
2  KL5077                    Power work
3  KL5147                 Planned works
4  KL7110                     BTS works
5  KS5007                     BSS works
```

Comment: @BakhytgulAzhigaliyeva glad it helps :)

Comment: don't you mind If I ask something else according to this file?)

Comment: Now editting files look like that:Column1 Column2
KL7110 after this KS5007
KL5066 Planned works
KL5147 Planned works
KL5066 Unplanned work
KL5077 Power work
KL5077 Power work
AN9045 MW work      I wanna delete same value from Column 2 for one value in column1. For example here is 2 KL5077 in column1 with same value in coumn2 I would Like to delete one of them. And second problem here is 2 KL5066 in Column1 with different value in Column2 and in this case I would like to put values in Column2 together like  "Planned work/Unplanned work". Hope I ve explained well))

Comment: @BakhytgulAzhigaliyeva it's difficult because of the formatting. Could you update the question with this new example?

Comment: Yes ofc, I ve added)

Comment: @BakhytgulAzhigaliyeva I've updated the answer, hope this helps

Comment: df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True) - this code will drop all duplicates for different values in column 1. I mean if in column 1 will be, for example, KS5077 and AN4955 with values in Column 2 Power Work(for both), it means the code with think they duplicate each other and delete them?

Comment: I updated to only explicitly use "Column1" and "Column2" when dropping duplicates, but yes, it will only drop rows where both of those columns have the same values - and it will leave 1 version of that row

Comment: Thank you, Chris! You helped a lot!

Comment: @BakhytgulAzhigaliyeva no problem. Happy coding :)